# Secant method in Matlab

Tags: algorithms, matlab

[image]
[image]

I have done following, but I don't know how to put that function into this:

```
function [x,y] = secant(fun,x0,x1,tol,max)
x(1) = x0;
x(2) = x1;
y(1) = feval(fun,x(1));
y(2) = feval(fun,x(2));
    for i = 3 : max
        x(i) = x(i-1) - y(i-1)/((y(i-1)-y(i-2))/(x(i-1)-x(i-2)));
        y(i) = feval(fun,x(i));
        if abs(x(i) - x(i-1)) < tol
            disp('Secant method converged!');
            break;
        end
        if i== max
            disp('Zero not found!');
        end
    end
n = length(x);
k = 1:n;
out = [k' x' y']; 

disp(out);
```

Comment: what is  basic question?does not it work?

Comment: Put what function into it? It looks like you have it most of it done and just need to test and debug it. You can always check if it's working by using a function for which you know the zeros, e.g., an arbitrary quadratic. Just choose `x0` and `x1` to straddle one of the zeros of the quadratic and you should get that `abs(fun(y(end))) < tol`. Something you want to look at is whether your termination condition is correct. Should it be `x(i) - x(i-1) < tol` like you have or should it be `abs(y(i)) < tol`?